# Можно ли вернуть результат startActivityForResult в другое активити?

Tags: java, android, activity

Всем привет!
Есть Activity1 со списком записей, из которой я нажимаю кнопку добавления записи и запускаю startActivityForResult для AddActivity. При успешном добавлении, возвращаю результат в Activity1. В Activity2 также есть кнопка для добавления. При нажатии кнопки я открываю AddActivity уже из Activity2, но после добавления записи мне нужно перейти к их списку и обновить его в Activity1. Подскажите, возможно ли стартовать из одной активити, а результат вернуть в другую?

UPD:
Без finish() не работало:

```
class ActivityThree extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE  = "message";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Some message"));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Условно вы запускаете Activity 1 из нее Activity 2, а из Activity 2 - Activity 3.

Собственно если вы хотите из Activity 3 прокинуть result в Activity 1 вам просто нужно в Activity 2 в методе `onActivityResult()` получить результат, вытянуть из `Intent-a` данные и положить их в Activity 2 в метод `setResult()`

**P.S.** Небольшой пример:

ActivityOne:

```
class ActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // do something
            String message = data.getStringExtra(ActivityThree.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    void startActivityTwo() {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class), REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

ActivityTwo:

```
class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        }
    }

    void startActivityThree() {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityThree.class), REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

ActivityThree:

```
class ActivityThree extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE  = "message";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Some message"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё оказывается проще, чем я думал)

Comment: Накидал небольшой пример

Comment: Bavaka, дополнил инфу в своём вопросе.

Comment: Ну если вам нужно сразу закрывать активити то надо вызывать finish, я на примере просто показал как передать результат дальше, а закрыть вы можете тогда когда вам это необходимо